# Refund to old credit card

Tags: banking

I sent back a pair of cleats to Nike and they issued the refund to the card that was originally billed. I assumed it would go to checking account, but it never did. Wells Fargo told me I have never had a Visa debit card ending in 9106. Is there any way for me or Nike to trace which institution the refund was sent to. The only thing I can think of is it could have been a pre paid Visa card. If so is there any way to trace. I find it hard to believe Nike has no way of tracing exactly where it went.

Comment: Did you discard your prepaid Visa card? Some prepaid cards don't allow reloading, so the money can sit in limbo at the issuing bank, in which case you should contact them. Nike would just have the card number, they wouldn't have other information to provide you.

Comment: First, a country tag would be useful for financial questions like this as regulations vary. Second, Bobby is correct, depending on "how" the fund were disbursed, you might be in an awkward situation. The thing you CAN generally ask for is for Nike to provide you the slip copy of the "refund" (aka the transactional record) and take that to where it was sent (assuming Well's Fargo) and they can trace the transaction id to find out "where" the money is now and if the ID is validated to be you and matches their records, they often release it to you but it's a huge hassle.

Comment: Another way to proceed would be to note that you haven't received the money and get Nike to check if the refund got bounced back, and request for payment to a different card/account

Comment: So you don't know what card you used to buy them? Was the refund a separate transaction, or a reversal of the original?

Answer (score 1):

Get the credit card number that the refund was issued to. The first 6 digits are called the "bank identification number" or "issuer identification number" and identify the bank (or whatever sort of institution) issued the card. You can look this up on the Internet and get their name and phone number. For example, http://www.issueridentificationnumber.com/

Comment: Clever, but if Nike has stored anything more than the last 4 digits of her card then they're in violation of PCI compliance. By contract they should not have or be able to provide this information.

Comment: Umm, SOMEBODY must know the full credit card number, or how did they bill the account? Companies routinely store my full credit card number, because they bill my card every month. PII rules require companies to protect this information, but they don't say you can't store it. Maybe there are restrictions on when and how, but I'm a software developer and I've never been told we can't store it, just what we have to do to protect it.

Comment: When a credit card number is provided to a merchant, they forward it to Visa. Visa authorizes the transaction and returns a tokenized/hash version of the account number. The merchant can store this token and the last 4 digits of the card. To rebill, the token is what gets forwarded to Visa instead of the original card number. *Visa* always knows what the account number is, but the entire PCI system is designed so that the merchant *never does*. When the merchant gets hacked, the compromised tokens can be voided without needing to issue new cards. PII is not PCI-- two **very** different beasts.

Comment: @Ivan+ PCI allows merchant to store (full) PAN _if_ it is encrypted to certain standards; tokenization is permitted as an alternative, and often a good idea for reducing scope, but not required. See DSS 3.4. DSS also allows displaying to staff up to first 6 _and_ last 4, although law/regulation or brand policies can be more restrictive, as could Nike's own choices. There was a prior scheme, SET, that did entirely prevent merchant from ever seeing PAN, but that flopped.

Comment: @Ivan "When a credit card number is provided to a merchant, they forward it to Visa. Visa authorizes the transaction and returns a tokenized/hash version of the account number." Visa doesn't make authorization decisions, they just forward the authorization request to the issuing bank.